# Github link oneboxer for Chat

Tags: script, chat, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

### Oneboxes links to Github repos, issues or pull requests in Chat

This userscript will automatically detect **new *and* existing** messages in chat that link to Github and onebox them, just like it is done already for posts on SE sites. Inspired by [One-box repositories, issue tickets and such on GitHub in the chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243259/260841) on Meta.

Issues will also show the milestone, labels and assignee in version 1.1.

### Screenshots

> [image]
> [image]

### Install

I recommend you use a userscript manager such as Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey because they make it much easier for you to manager userscripts.

<kbd>[View source](https://github.com/shu8/SEChat-githubOneboxer/blob/master/githubOneboxer.user.js)</kbd> or <kbd>[Install](https://github.com/shu8/SEChat-githubOneboxer/raw/master/githubOneboxer.user.js)</kbd>

Feature requests and bug reports are welcome as issues at the [Github repo](https://github.com/shu8/SEChat-githubOneboxer). Pull requests are even more welcome! ;)

You can test it in any chat room, or in [the Sandbox](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/651/); [just like I did](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/651/conversation/github-link-oneboxer-testing) :)

I posted this on Code Review to get it reviewed and have updated the script after receiving some tips on improvement! :)

Answer (score 2):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) https://github.com/shu8/SEChat-githubOneboxer/issues/1

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Show labels, milestones and assignee in ticket oneboxes.

For example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Will look at it - mind adding an issue at github? :)